# Rails render incorrect format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I’m trying to render template with format.js but I get render with html format. If I make render with `respond to`, everything works fine and I get js format rendered. Render string looks like:

```
def render_alert(message, opts = {})
  locals = opts.slice(:title, :type)
  locals[:type] ||= 'info'
  locals.merge!(message: message)
  render_params = {
      partial: 'layouts/alert',
      locals: locals

  }
  render render_params
end
```

request.format.to_sym shows :js
everything works well if change last string to

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js do
    render render_params
  end
  format.html do
    render render_params
  end
end
```

any ideas what can be wrong? Request format is correct:

```
p 'render_params', render_params, request.format.to_sym
render render_params
```

[image]

UPDATE:
if this function is being called from controller, everything works well, but renders html if it's being called from rescue block in before_action:

```
rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
  if request.xhr?
    render_alert(exception.message, type: 'error')
  else
    url = request.referrer
    ref_uri = URI.parse(url) rescue nil
    url = root_url if url.blank? || ref_uri&.host != request.domain
    redirect_to url, :alert => exception.message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try pass format to render method, like this:

```
locals = opts.slice(:title, :type)
locals[:type] ||= 'info'
locals.merge!(message: message)
render_params = {
    partial: 'layouts/alert',
    locals: locals
}

render render_params, format: request.format.to_sym
```

I try here, and works fine :D

My test code:

**Controller**

```
  def teste
    render_params = {partial: 'layouts/alert', locals: {type: 'error', message: 'You are not authorized to access this page.'}}
    render render_params, format: request.format.to_sym
  end
```

**View**

**layout/_alert.js.erb**

```
alert('<%= message %>');
```

**layout/_alert.js.erb**

```
<h1><%= message %></h1>
```

**Result JS:**

[image]

**Result HTML:**

[image]

Comment: this code should render html and js both. And I have both templates: http://joxi.net/ZrJ8Meu9KwjD2j

Comment: also I've just tried to specify format, and nothing changed - html is still being rendered

Comment: doesn't work for me, still have `Rendered layouts/_alert.html.slim`